# Negation of a statement regarding a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, predicate-logic

I am trying to negate the following statement:

If $(x_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence, $x_n \in K$ (where $K$ is a set) $\forall n>0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \in K$

I believe the answer is either:

If $\exists$ a sequence $ (x_i)$  with $x_i \in K$ (where $K$ is a  set) $\forall i>0$ and $\lim \limits_{i \to \infty}x_i=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \notin K$

or:

If $\exists$ a sequence $ (x_i)$ with $x_i \in K$ (where $K$ is a set) for some $i>0$ and $\lim \limits_{i \to \infty}x_i=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \notin K$

Would someone be able to explain **logically**   (not using rules) why one is correct over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The statement is true. Please check the definition of a closed set.
2. Changing finitely many terms of a sequence does not influence its limit, i.e. the limit does not depend on the first $n$ terms for any fixed $n$. Intuitively, the limit is something the sequence tends to, and changing the first few steps do not influence what it tends to.

Edit: Given your edited question, the statement could be disproved by a counter example, e.g $K=(0,1)$, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

If $K$ is closed the statement is true. Otherwise both can happen. Of course our discussion is in the topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Edit_2: It seems that I have drastically misunderstood your question. If you only want the negation of that statement, it should be: There exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset K$ converging in $\mathbb{R}$ to $x$ such that $x\notin K$.

This condition does imply that $K$ is not closed, since $x$ is a limit point of $K$ but is not in $K$.

If we analyzed your answer, we could reformulate it as: if there exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset K$ converging in $\mathbb{R}$ to $x$, then $x\notin K$. I don't think this makes much sense...

I believe your confusion is with the quantifier? Your initial statement is of the form: FOR ANY "thing" that satisfies a certain property $P$, this "thing" satisfies another property $Q$. So the negation should be of the form: THERE EXISTS a thing that satisfies property $P$, but does not satisfy property $Q$

Comment: I'm wondering what the negation of the statement is in order to prove a set is not closed. What is the correct negation and why? (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The negation of a statement of the form "if $ A $ then $ B $" is "$ A $ and not $ B $".

In your statement,

$ A $ is "$(x_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence, $x_n \in K$ (where $K$ is a set) $\forall n>0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$".

$ B $ is "$ x \in K $".

Therefore not $ B $ is "$ x \notin K $".

Hence the negation of your statement is "$(x_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence, $x_n \in K$ (where $K$ is a set) $\forall n>0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ **and**  $x \notin K$".

In other word, the negation(for your statement) is

**for each sequence $(x_n)$ of $K$, the limit of $(x_n)$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ but it does not belong to $K$.**

But, if $K$ is a closed set then for each sequence $(x_n)$ of $K$, the limit of $(x_n)$ is also belong to $K$.

Therefore if then there exists a sequence  $(x_n)$ of $K$ such that the limit of $(x_n)$ does not belong to $K$ then $K$ is not closed. This is called the **contraposition** of the above statement.

Comment: For the negation i'm pretty sure it doesn't have to hold for all $(x_n)$, just one of them proves it is not closed. I don't understand why the negation of $A \implies B$ is $A$ and not $B$.

Comment: $ p\Rightarrow q $ is logically equivalent to $ \urcorner p\vee q $. So, $ \urcorner(p\Rightarrow q) $ is equivalent to $  \urcorner (\urcorner p\vee q)\equiv p\wedge \urcorner q $. Therefore the negation for the "given" statement is "for each sequence $(x_n)$ of $K$, the limit of $(x_n)$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ but it does not belong to $K$." But it is not the condition for $K$ is not closed. we say $K$ is closed if limit of every sequence of $K$ belongs to itself. so, if there exists a sequence  $(x_n)$ of $K$ so that the limit of $(x_n)$ does not belong to $K$ then we say $K$ is not closed.

Comment: for more details about logic see the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong.  A closed set does in fact contain all of its limit points.  The statement you are trying to negate is actually true.  Instead, try to convince yourself that if $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed, and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points in $K$ converging to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \in K$.

One additional note, we tend to write $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x$ or $x_n \to x$, but we never write $\lim_{x_n \to \infty} = x$.

Comment: I understand what you have stated, but I am trying to negate this statement to provide me with a way of proving a set is **not** closed

Comment: Apologies I should not have wrote that $K$ was closed. $K$ is any set